# Different between rotating the camera vs rotating the scene point (only the point, not the entire scene)?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, rotational-matrices

I think rotating the camera and taking the photo of a scene would yield the same result with keeping the camera stable and rotating the scene in reverse way.

Assume that the original camera rotation matrix is R1. Rotating the camera means that we apply another rotation matrix R12 (so R2=R12*R1 is the new rotation matrix). Assume that X is the realworld coordinate of scene point. Rotating the scene point in the reverse way means that we apply the reverse rotation matrix R12^-1 to X (this might be wrong).

So why (R12*R1)*X **!=** R1*(R12^-1*X) ?

Can anyone explain me what I'm wrong?

p.s. I'm not asking about programing as well as complexity of the two method. I just want to know

(1) the mathematical equation for the action "rotating the scene"

(2) if my assumed equation for "rotating the scene" is correct, why doesn't the mathematical equations reflect the phenomenon in the real world as I described.

**Edit 1**: According to **Spektre**'s answer, when I rotate the entire scene with the rotation matrix R, then the new camera rotation matrix is

```
R^-1*R1
```

In this case, I rotate the entire scene with the rotation matrix R12^-1, then the new camera rotation matrix is

```
(R12^-1)^-1*R1=R12*R1
```

However, what if I consider that rotating the camera is equivalent to rotating the scene point X (**only** the scene point X, not the entire scene). At that time, the rotation matrix of the camera is still R1. But the scene point X now become X'. And the image coordinate of X' is R1*X'. **What is the equation for X' ?** Note that

```
R1*X' = R12*R1*X
```

Of course, you can answer that

```
X'=R1^-1*R12*R1*X
```

But I think X' should be defined only by R12 and X (R1 doesn't need to be known to form X'). That's why I ask "what is the mathematical equation for rotating the scene point". X' is the result of the action "rotating X" by some rotation matrix related to R12.

I have another example when the camera does not rotate but move. Assume that I'm taking the photo of a model who is standing right in front of me. Her position is X. My position is C. In the first case, I move to the right (of me) and take the first photo. In the second case, I don't move but the model move the left (of me) with the same steps and I take the second photo. The position of the model in the two image must be identical. This is expressed by the mathematical equation

```
[R1 -R1*(C+d)]*X = [R1 -R1*C]*(X-d)
```

In the equation above (which I checked to be true), -R1*C is the translation vector, -R1*(C+d) is the translation vector when I move to the right of me, (X-d) is the position of the model when she move to the left of me.

In the above example, X' = X-d (so X' is defined through X and my movement d). In the case of rotating the camera, what is X'?

**Edit 2**: Since **Spektre** still don't understand my question. There's a need to emphasize that in the second case, I DO NOT rotate the ENTIRE world, I ONLY rotate the point X. (If I rotate the entire world, the world coordinate of X remains the same after its world rotate. But if I rotate only X, its world coordinate will be changed to X').

Just imagine the example about taking the photo of the model. In the first case, I rotate the camera and take the first photo of her (and her boy friend standing next to her).

In the second case, I rotate ONLY the model in the reverse direction (her boy friend is stable), then I take the second photo. When I compare the two photos, the position of the model is the same (the position of her boy friend would be different).

In both case, the real world position of her boy friend are the same. But the real world position of the model is changed in the second case since I rotated her. My question is what is the real world position of the girl after I rotate her?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to Title is:** mathematically they are both almost the same (except inversion of all operations) but physically rotating camera means changing single matrix but to rotate scene you have to rotate all the objects in your world (can be thousands and more) which is a lot slower ...

**But I assume** the title and text is misleading as **the real question is** about linear algebra matrix equations.

Let `R1,R2,R12` be square matrices of size `N x N` and `X` is vector of size `N`. If we ignore the vector orientation (`1 x N` vs `N x 1`) then for your convention:

```
R2 = R12.R1
R1 = Inverse(R12).R2
```

so:

```
R12.R1.X == R12.Inverse(R12).R2.X == R2.X
```

As you can see equation in your Question is wrong because you change the matrix multiplication order which is wrong because:

```
R1.R12 != R12.R1
```

If you want to know more closely why then study linear algebra.

**[Edit1] simple `1x1` example**

let:

```
R1 = 1
R12= 2
R2 = R12.R1 = 2
```

so rewriting your wrong equation:

```
R12*R1*X != R1*Inverse(R12)*X
  2* 1*X !=  1*         0.5*X
     2*X != 0.5*X
```

and using the correct one

```
R12*R1*X == R12*Inverse(R12)*R2*X == R2*X
  2* 1*X ==   2*         0.5* 2*X ==  2*X
     2*X == 2*X == 2*X
```

**[Edit2] simple 2D example**

I see you are still confused so here an **2D** example of the problem:

[image: 2D exmaple]

On the left you got rotated camera by `R1` so for rendering transforming world point `(x,y)` into its local coordinates `(x1,y1)`. On the right is the situation reversed so camera coordinate system is axis aligned (unit matrix) and the scene is rotated in reverse by `Inverse(R1)`. That is how it works (where `R1` is the relative matrix in this case).

Now if I try to port it to your matrix names and convention so the relative matrix is `R12` and `R1` is the camera :

```
(R1.R12).(x,y) = (x1,y1)
Inverse(R1.R12).(x1,y1) = (x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I'm asking is totally different with what you answer. 

I'm not asking about programing as well as the complexity.

Comment: My question is that why the mathematic equation doesn't reflect the situation in the real world. 

In the real world, I rotate the camera then taking the first photo. The second photo is taken with the camera kept stable, but the scene is rotated in the reverse way. In the REAL WORLD, I think the two images would be the same. (If not, please explain me why)

My first question is: what is the mathematic equation for the action "rotating the scene in the reverse way"? 

Is it R12^-1*X ?

My second question is: If so, why (R12*R1)*X != R1*(R12^-1)*X ?

Comment: @JamesDo So I was right after all you just did not read the rest of the answer (after: "But I assume")  You can not change the matrix order. Yes inverse matrix is the reverse operation. if `Y = R12.X` then `(R12^-1).Y = X` The equations in your last comment make no sense possibly you should have `R2` somewhere instead of `R1` The equation should be: `R12.R1.X == R12.Inverse(R12).R2.X == R2.X`

Comment: You still don't understand what I'm asking. I'm very aware that matrix multiplication is not commutative. All of your equation is obviously right to me. I'm asking about the euation for the situation "keep the camera stable, then rotate the scene in the reverse way and take the picture". Since I keep the camera stable, the camera rotation is still R1. And what is the methematic representation for the rotated scene point X.

Comment: For the first image, I rotate the camera with the rotation matrix R12, the scene point is table. Then the image coordinate of X is : (R12*R1) *X. 

For the second image, I keep the camera stable, but I rotate the scene point in the reverse way (i.e. R12^-1). Then the image cooordinate of X is: R1* (R12^-1*X)

My equation for "rotating the scene point in the reverse way" ( R12^-1 * X) migh be wrong.

Comment: so you mean that the equation for "keep the camera stable, rotate the scene in the reverse way, take the picture" is (R12^-1)*R1*X

But still, why the equation doesn't reflect the fact that the images in two case are the same?

Comment: It seems that I understand the problem. So "rotate the camera, take the picture" and "rotate the scene in reverse way, take the picture" have the same rotation matrix, which is R2=R12*R1. If I rotate the scene by the rotation matrix R3, then the equation should be "R3^-1*R1*X". In this case, R3=R12^-1, therefore the rotation matrix is (R12^-1)^-1*R1=R12*R1.

Thank you very much for you help :D

Comment: I've clarified my question. Could you answer again Spektre?

Comment: In the second case, I DO NOT rotate the ENTIRE WORLD, I just rotate ONLY the point X. If I rotate the entire world, the world coordinate of X are the same. But If I rotate only X, its coordinate in the world will change. The new world coordinate of X is X'. Just imagine my example about taking photo of the model. In the first case, I rotate the camera and take her photo. In the second case, I only rotate the model  in the reverse direction (her boy friend standing next to her is still stable). The position of the model in both image are the same.

Comment: @JamesDo Yes and my equations reflects exactly that but Yours are not. I see there is no point to continue this without specific sample input from your side ... (I mean the sketch, the angles and the taken or rendered images ...) otherwise we will go in circles forewer